# .Net compiler hooking

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, compiler-construction

All my data objects implement an interface IFillable

```
Public Interface IFillable
    Sub Fill(ByVal Datareader As Data.IDataReader)
End Interface
```

In the objects themselves you will typically see something like

```
Public Class Supplier
    Implements IFillable

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Sub New(ByVal SupplierID As Guid, ByVal CompanyID As Guid, ByVal Description As String)
        Me._SupplierID = SupplierID
        Me._CompanyID = CompanyID
        Me._Description = Description
    End Sub

    Public Property SupplierID As Guid
    Public Property CompanyID As Guid
    Public Property Description As String

    Public Sub Fill(ByVal Datareader As System.Data.IDataReader) Implements IFillable.Fill
        If Not Datareader.IsClosed Then
            Me._SupplierID = Datareader.GetGuid(Datareader.GetOrdinal("SupplierID"))
            Me._CompanyID = Datareader.GetGuid(Datareader.GetOrdinal("CompanyID"))
            Me._Description = Datareader.GetString(Datareader.GetOrdinal("Description"))
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Now here is the tricky bit. Given that all my property names ***WILL ALWAYS*** match my database column names what I want to do is using reflection generate the fill method at compile time and infer the types and column names for the datareader.

I am assuming I will need to structure this functionality as some sort of a tool/vs plugin? What I am looking for is guidance on the best way to go about this.

PS: BTW: Obviously I could easily do this using reflection at runtime but I dont want to take the performance hit for it (Although theoretically if I could cache the values somehow (static class?) it might not be too bad).

Comment: could you theoretically use Linq to SQL or Entity Framework and avoid this dirty work?

Comment: Why don't you use a simple generator in a 'before-build' step to create the code.

Comment: Actually not a bad idea, although it would be nice to plug straight into the compiler. Might investigate your approach...

Comment: @Barfieldmv do you want to put your comment as an answer so I can mark it correct? I've gone with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a simple generator in a 'before-build' step to create the code.

We've created our own code generator that generates an in code Data Layer when triggered manually after a database definition change.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use some code generation framework.
For VB/C#/.NET the most obvious choice should be T4:
[some T4 introduction](http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/text-template-transformation-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

You could look at “[aspect-oriented programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)” systems for C#, some of them work at compile time, e.g

> [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/postsharp) reads .NET binary modules to
>   an object model, let plugins analyze
>   and transform it, then writes it back
>   to MSIL.

There is a list of them [here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/aspect-oriented-frameworks), I have never used any of them on a project but have thought of doing so for problems like yours.

A source code generation framework is also a good opion and can be a lot easer to understand what is going on.